# Google Chrome won't cache content

Tags: http, node.js, google-chrome, caching

I've been searching all over for a solution to this, but so far nothing. I am dynamically rendering an HTML page in Node.js/Express, generating an ETag by SHA256 hashing the HTML string, and sending the page through nginx. For some reason, Google Chrome won't cache the page or send an "If-None-Match" header for the previous ETag.

Here are my request and response headers:

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.logan.oikoi.co
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.82 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: km_ai=Q%2FR9nmmebaNLthhixes8jxMubzQ%3D; km_uq=; kvcd=1346083163009; km_vs=1; km_lv=1346083163
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2012 06:20:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
ETag: "2e26404f4306e4d2a7c821f537aa3e714d655d260462f8a7fdd9f0a8ad501900"
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=rPrRyvqf3LhbilN0syPU3htr.776UPuqojSyF1YgS0AFcyac4qQtv%2FXF9TFSHQ96p6e8; path=/; expires=Sun, 26 Aug 2012 10:20:46 GMT; httpOnly; secure
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Edit: I forgot to mention in my initial post, but Firefox has no problem caching the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your response has these headers -

> > Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
> >
> > Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Remove these headers and you should be good.

FYI :

1. must-revalidate forces the browser to make a request every time the resource is request
2. Expires header and max-age=0 tell the browser to not cache the resource

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I tried removing those two headers, but the browser still will not cache the content or send an "If-None-Match" header. 

As for why I tried the must-revalidate, the pages being rendered are dynamic and change sporadically - I want to save bandwith by not serving a page unnecessarily, while still checking if a page is fresh with each request.